# Swift Error Message: "Value of type 'city' has no member 'id'

Tags: swift, types, member, guard

I have established the code below and the variable 'cityId', but I am getting an error: "Value of type 'city' has no member 'id'. Any help is appreciated.  Code getting error is in bold.

```
public func loadForecast(for city: City, callback: @escaping (_
    response:WeatherResponse?, _ error:LoadingError?) -> () ) {
        **guard let cityId = city.id else** {
        callback(nil, LoadingError.invalidCity)
        return
    }
```

Comment: Error Message: "Value of type 'City' has no member 'id'

Comment: The error message is pretty clear and self-explanatory

Comment: what is `City`?